# Is it possible to only iterate through a certain index in a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists where the indexes across the internal lists houses the same type of information. If I only want to iterate through that index for each list, is this a valid statement?

```
for item in list_of_lists[:][0]:
    doSomething()
```

Comment: Why don't you run it and see?

Comment: Should `item` not be an argument of `doSomething()` then? (Because you would use `item[0]` instead.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could iterate over your lists of lists and access each inner lists at your wanted index:

```
my_index = <some integer>

for item in lists_of_lists:
    doSomething(item[my_index])
```

Answer (score 0):

With a numpy array your code would work.

With lists, you should do that :

```
# Some test data
list_of_lists = [
  [ 0,  1,  2,  3  ],
  [ 10, 11, 12 ,13 ],
  [ 20, 21, 22, 23 ],
  [ 30, 31, 32, 33 ]
]
index = 2 # the sublists index you want to iterate on

for item in ( sublist[index] for sublist in list_of_lists ):
  #doSomething() # Commented out for the demonstration to work
  print(item) # A print to see the values of item that you can remove
```

Output :

```
2
12
22
32
```

This iterates through a generator yielding the item at `my_index` for each sub-lists in `list_of_lists`.

Note that you can use the generator anywhere you need an iterable.

(I assumed `doSomething()` is just a placeholder for your "useful code", if not, item is not passed to the function)

Answer (score 0):

If you have inner lists whch holds the same info, and you want to iterate only on first inner just do :

```
[[1,2,3,4],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [1,2,3,4],]

# iterate on 1,2,3,4
for item in list_of_lists[0]: # list_of_lists[0] is the 1st inner list
    doSomething(item)

# iterate on 2,2,2,2
for inner_list in list_of_lists: 
    doSomething(inner_list[1])
```

Comment: OP says "the indexes across the internal lists houses the same type of information" not only on first inner

Answer (score 0):

If you would do operation on colums rather than rows multiple times, consider transposing your data, for example:

```
list_of_lists = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
transposed = list(zip(*list_of_lists))
print(transposed)  # [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
for item in transposed[1]:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
2
5
```

Note that this solution is useful only if you do not plan to alter content of `list_of_lists`

Comment: it's correct, but I think it's not easily readable, and not optimized because you go through the whole data, and not only the index wanted. But there is clearly an educational interest to see zip in action for transposing data